# Explanation of a Tosfos on Kesubos 111a; ד"ה בבלה

Tags: commentaries, eretz-yisrael, tosfot, maseches-kesubos, yirmiyahu--book-of

I was reading the Gemara about whether it is permissible to emigrate from Babylonia to Eretz Yisrael [(Kesubos 111a)](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.111a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en). Rav Yehudah holds that whoever ascends from Babylonia to Eretz Yisrael, transgresses a positive commandment. Rav Yehudah points to a posuk in [Yirmiyahu (27:22)](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.27.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> they shall be carried to Bavel, and there shall they be until the day
> that I take heed of them, says the L-rd; then will I bring them up,
> and restore them to this place.

Although the refutation of R' Zeira seems very logical, that's not what I am looking for.

The Tosfos [(תוספות ד"ה בבלה)](https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Ketubot.111a.1.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains:

> בבלה יובאו ושמה יהיו - אע"ג דהאי קרא בגלות ראשון כתיב י"ל דבגלות שני נמי קפיד קרא

There are several summaries of this Tosfos, see for example [here](https://dafyomi.co.il/kesuvos/tosfos/ks-ts-111.htm) and [here](https://alldaf.org/t/Kesuvos/111/Tosfos). However, the summaries seems to me a little bit too simplistic. For [example](https://alldaf.org/t/Kesuvos/111/Tosfos):

> It is possible to answer that the Pasuk must also have been stringent that people should not go back to Eretz Yisrael (in this fashion) after the second exile.

Why does the Tosfos say it is possible? Is it logic?

I am looking for explanations on this Tosfos (seforim on Tosfos for example).

Comment: The Tosfos Harash changed the word of “it’s possible to say” to Mistavra, “it’s logical”

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Rest the question why.

Comment: I would imagine that the logic is that the same reason Hashem wanted them to stay there until the end of the first galus, He would want the same thing for the next galus.

Comment: @Chatzkel Rashi on Yirmiyahu 27:22 says that "until the day I remember them" refers to the days of Cyrus. Thus how can we say it refers to our time also? The view of the Satmar Rav is: the Pnei Yehoshua writes this only because he learns that the Three Oaths took effect at the beginning of the Babylonia exile, after the destruction of the First Beis Hamikdash.